# Do we have option of using snap shot in ALM as psf in SVN?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rtc, alm

In eclipse we have possibility to create psf file using Export --> Team Project set and use that psf to create new workspace code.

Is there a similar possbility in ALM to get the information out of snapshot and use it as psf?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly like a project set file (psf), but in RTC, you can memorize the exact state of multiple repos (here in RTC "components") with a stream.

By communicating the stream name, any collaborator can create a repo workspace on that stream and checkout (in his/her own sandbox) the components.

That is what you find in [this thread for instance](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/54726/configuring-project-coming-from-svn)::

> Instead of a `.psf` file, you would use an RTC stream.
>
> - When someone has changes that they want to make visible to the rest of
>     the team, instead of updating the `.psf` file, they would **deliver** their
>     changes to the RTC stream.
> - Conversely, when you want to catch up to
>     the changes being made by other team members, you would accept changes
>     from stream (rather than pulling a set of tags).

See also [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/2613/sharing-working-sets):

A **team project-set** (Eclipse) can be exported to a **`.psf`** file while working-sets are part of your preferences.

> The team project-set was added to eclipse to augment SCM systems which didn't make it easy to bootstrap and get the right line-up of projects.
>
> In Jazz we recommend you setup a stream with the component/projects your team members need to work on and they can simply create their own repo workspace and load it.
>   When a repo workspace is loaded, we automatically create a working-set for each component that is loaded, as the documentation quote above mentions.

Comment: If a create a new release i will tag the code for different projects in SVN and create a psf file. So for example release 1.0 and 2.0 can have many projects in different svn locations. I can see the difference in the psf file of two releases easily. IN rtc what is the easiest way of acheiving it?

Comment: @user3302323 `scm diff` is one possibility: https://jazz.net/forum/questions/107966/file-comparison-to-display-lines-changed-on-2-streams-using-rtc-cli: Through the GUI, you can compare streams as well: https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.concert.dotnet.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_comparing_baselines.html